# How to Load more than one source into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code. It works for one sourc, but when I try to load a second url in there it doesnt work like I want it to.

```
$(function(){
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
        var fullUrl1 = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
            $.ajax({
              url: fullUrl,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
              }, 
              success: onSuccess,
              error: onError
            });
            $.ajax({
              url: fullUrl1,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
              "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
              success: onSuccess,
              error: onError
            });
```

Comment: I feel like I am close, but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Promise function to then load in data, where you can use as many urls as you need, just make sure you correctly concatenate them.

Here:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  Promise.all([
    loadData("EmployeeInfo", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree"),
    loadData("Employee2", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree"),
  ])
    .then(([r1, r2]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="employeeTab" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>Age</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Position</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Office</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Education</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Degree</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Source</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";
```